# how to pass data in Python3 requests to VMware workstation api?

Tags: python, python-requests, vmware-workstation

**The problem:**

i am trying to initiate a power on command for my virtual machine. i am able to do so in the windows command line, with curl passing the problematic data with

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:8697/api/vms/vm_id/power" -X PUT --header "Content-Type: application/vnd.vmware.vmw.rest-v1+json" --header "Accept: application/vnd.vmware.vmw.rest-v1+json" --header "Authorization: Basic MyToken" -d on                                                                                       
{"power_state": "poweredOn}
```

i don't understand the consept of headers and data very well. all i know is i need to insert operation " on " inside a body of a post request. i pitty the RAM on my pc, for all those chrome tabs that have remained open. Seems i' ve hit a brick wall. Any help apriciated in advance.

**Code:**

```
import requests
import json

api_token = MyToken
desired_vm_id = vm_id
headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.vmware.vmw.rest-v1+json','Authorization': 'Basic {0}'.format(api_token)}
api_url_base = 'http://127.0.0.1:8697/api/vms/'

def get_vm_status():
    api_url = '{0}{1}/power'.format(api_url_base, desired_vm_id)
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        response = json.loads(response.content)
        if (response['power_state']) == 'poweredOff':
          response_for_put = requests.put(api_url, headers = headers, data = {'operation': 'on'})
          result = json.loads(response_for_put.content)
          print(result['Message'])
        else:
          print('VM already running:', response)  
    else:
        return None        

get_vm_status()
```

**Result**:

```
Content type not supported
```

**Documentation:**
[from vmware workstation pro dockumentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFvUY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the `Content-Type` header in your `curl` command but not in your Python code.  Try changing this line:

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.vmware.vmw.rest-v1+json','Authorization': 'Basic {0}'.format(api_token)}
```

to this:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.vmware.vmw.rest-v1+json', 'Accept': 'application/vnd.vmware.vmw.rest-v1+json','Authorization': 'Basic {0}'.format(api_token)}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the root of the problem, i did not notice, i had one header missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
response = requests.put(api_url, headers=headers, data='on')
```

You can then read JSON response directly:

```
response.json()
```

Comment: Interesting.  I was looking at the documentation, while you saw what was actually being sent in the `curl` request.  Now I'm really confused, since A) the documentation discusses sending JSON, B) the `curl` command says its sending JSON, but C) the `curl` command is sending raw data.  - well, maybe one of the two changes will work for the OP.

Comment: and thank you too, after fixing the missing header, data = 'on'  was accepted data format.